# How to calculate the mean of last five rows in Python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

How do I calculate the mean value of a column of the last five rows in Python pandas?
E.g. I have the following dataset:

```
Year | KGV
---- | ----
2008 | 8.35
2009 | 30.22
2010 | 18.04
2011 | 15.71
2012 | 26.82
2013 | 24.64
2014 | 24.52
```

How can I calculate the KGV mean of the last five rows ? I know I could simply create a new dataframe with `df.tail(5)` but is there a built-in way?

**EDIT**: Just found out, is `df['KGV'].tail(5).mean(axis=0)` the way to go?

Comment: `df['KGV'].tail().mean()` would work, also to be more explicit `df['KGV'].iloc[-5:].mean()` would also work

Comment: @EdChum What is the difference between these solutions?

Comment: `tail` by default returns last 5 rows, using `iloc` performs integer based indexing so it's more explicit in some sense but the end result is the same

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

`df['KGV'].tail(5).mean()`

compute mean of last tailing values of kgv

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
lastFive = df['KGV'].tail(5)
lastFive.mean()
```